# Message queue abstraction for Python?

Tags: python, abstraction, mq

There are many discussions on SO about database abstraction.  I'm a bit surprised there aren't similar discussions about message queue abstraction.  Rather than designing to a specific MQ implementation (RabbitMQ, IBM MQ Series, IronMQ etc.), we would prefer to use a neutral / abstracting layer, so the underlying implementation could be changed without major surgery later.

Can you recommend a solution?

Comment: In this case, I would recommend you yourself write the interface tailored to your needs.  Write the toolbox you're looking for as a sort of interface to underlying engines that do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most promising option so far appears to be [Kombu](https://github.com/ask/kombu) which is described as a high-level abstraction of the AMQ protocol (e.g. RabbitMQ) but supports several messaging back-ends that don't require AMQP, including REDIS, Beanstalk, Amazon SQS, CouchDB, MongoDB and Zookeeper -- in varying degrees.

I will give this a try and report back.  Kind of don't like answering and accepting my own question :) -- will look at other answers to and change the accepted one if yours is better.

Answer (score 0):

The most neutral way to handle a message queue is to just use a database to store your messages. If your app get's more complex you can switch to something more sophisticated.

Right now I'm using PeeWee ORM to handle the messages. During testing the database is set to use an SQLite instance. In production the postgres server is set. You could just use the sqlite if the app doesn't use a lot of write concurrency.

```py
from enum import Enum
from peewee import (  # type: ignore
    Model,
    CharField,
    DateTimeField,
    ForeignKeyField,
    Proxy,
    UUIDField,
    ModelSelect,
)
from peewee_extra_fields import EnumField  # type: ignore

PRODUCTION_DB_URL = "postgres://test_db_z9du_user:b5TWChOlCpKQRHcAg8u64kUpVIjNba5O@dpg-cc8ltahgp3jhesr2u9u0-a.oregon-postgres.render.com/test_db_z9du"  # pylint: disable=line-too-long
TEST_DB_PATH = str(HERE.parent / "data/test.db")
SQLITE_URL = f"sqlite:////{TEST_DB_PATH}".replace("\\", "/")
DB_URL = SQLITE_URL if IS_TESTING else PRODUCTION_DB_URL
if IS_TESTING:
    db_dir = os.path.dirname(TEST_DB_PATH)
    if not os.path.exists(db_dir):
        print(f"Creating test db directory {db_dir}")
        os.makedirs(db_dir, exist_ok=True)
    os.makedirs(db_dir, exist_ok=True)


database_proxy = Proxy()
database_proxy.initialize(connect(DB_URL))


class BaseModel(Model):
    """A base model that will use our Sqlite database."""

    class Meta:  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
        """Meta class."""

        database = database_proxy

database_proxy = Proxy()
database_proxy.initialize(connect(DB_URL))

class MessageStatusEnum(Enum):
    """Enum class for message status"""

    QUEUED = 1
    PROCESSING = 2
    ERROR = 3


class Message(BaseModel):
    """Message model."""

    user = ForeignKeyField(User, backref="messages", primary_key=True)
    type = CharField(index=True)
    message = CharField(null=True)
    last_error_msg = CharField(null=True)
    created = DateTimeField(index=True, default=datetime.now)
    status = EnumField(
        index=True, enum=MessageStatusEnum, default=MessageStatusEnum.QUEUED
    )  # MessageStatusEnum.QUEUED or MessageStatusEnum.PROCESSING
```

Example of how to use message queue:

```py
def pop_next_email_drm_task_for_processing(self) -> Message | None:
    """Pop the next email drm task."""
    try:
        with database_proxy.atomic():
            # get the first one
            cursor = (
                Message.select()
                .where(
                    Message.status == MessageStatusEnum.QUEUED and Message.type == "email_drm"
                )
                .order_by(Message.created)
                .limit(1)
            )
            message = cursor.first()
            if message is None:
                return None
            message.status = MessageStatusEnum.PROCESSING
            message.save()
            return message
```

Comment: In the general case, relational database make poor queues because of throughput limitations related to locking. Your approach can work fine for low-volume systems. The same approach can be done for somewhat higher-volume systems when the DB is Postgres due to their unique support for the UPDATE SKIP LOCKED operation — works up to maybe 10k messages per second. Above that, using a DB won’t work — you need something that’s purpose-built for queuing like AWS SQS that can handle millions of messages per second.

Comment: 10k messages per second is significant webscale though.  99% of projects won't have that kind of io pressure.

Comment: Agree that would suffice for many purposes. But it doesn’t make the DB design an abstraction of a message queue. It’s a particular (not abstracted) implementation choice. I would use it any time I know I don’t need more scale. I’d still prefer to have it behind an abstraction that makes substituting other implementations less disruptive to my overall design.

Comment: Are there any tiny message queue implementations that don't require advanced unix administration level of experience to install?